# How to create an updatable CoreML model?

Tags: ios, swift, coreml, createml

I have created an Image Classifier model using CreateML. Now I am trying to update that model using CoreML but I am unable to do so. I am getting this error "Pipeline is not marked as updatable to perform update."

Answer (score 1):

You need to mark the model inside the pipeline as being updatable, and also the pipeline itself. Plus, the model will need some settings, such as the type of optimizer to use etc.

More details here: https://machinethink.net/blog/coreml-training-part4/

Comment: Can you please explain how can I mark the model updatable in CreateML interface provided by XCode?

Comment: As far as I know, you can't do it in Create ML.